# Facebook Banner Ad Size

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-audience-network

I integrated facebook banner ad in my app, however I feel something is going wrong with the sizing.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    fbAdView = FBAdView.init(placementID: "***************", adSize: kFBAdSizeHeight90Banner, rootViewController: self)
    fbAdView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 90)
    fbAdView.delegate = self
    fbAdView.loadAd()
}

func adViewDidLoad(_ adView: FBAdView) {
    print("FBAd adViewDidLoad")
    adViewContainer.addSubview(fbAdView)
}
```

[image: Facebook ad size]

Comment: Show the code you have written so far so that we can try to help you.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana code added

Answer (score 1):

I just commented out this line and the banner looks fine now!

```
// fbAdView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 90)
```